# Open a zip file and move the file in another zip in c++?

Tags: c++, zip, libraries, minecraft

I wanted to open a zip file (mod.zip) and move the file inside, to another zip file (minecraft.zip) and owerwrite the file with same names.I hope you understand because im not english.
I dont know if i can open zip files or i need libraries

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [7zip SDK](http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html), it lets you zip and unzip things in `.7z` and `.zip` and many other formats

Comment: @user1993039 I would suggest then hiring a programmer. :)

Comment: well im going to study more asd i ll try to do it when i ll know more thank you